# DAX Find and repeat latest value and then aggregate

Tags: powerpivot, calculated-field, dax

I have tried to use the following DAX formula to find the latest granted credit limit for a customer (identified by the [EventTypeId] = 705) and this almost works fine for an individual customer, but I can't aggregate it over all customers as it will basically find the latest and largest credit limit available for any customer. Another problem is that for the periods where there are no transactions for the customer, the formula returns a null (no open balance, hence no daily interest calculation).

```
=IF (
MIN ( Dim_Vintage[VintageDay] )
    <= CALCULATE ( MAX ( Fact_AccountEvent[VintageDay] ) );
CALCULATE (
    MAX ( Fact_AccountEvent[Amount] );
    Fact_AccountEvent[EventTypeId] = 705;
    FILTER (
        ALL ( Dim_Vintage[VintageDay] );
        Dim_Vintage[VintageDay] <= MAX ( Dim_Vintage[VintageDay] )
    )
))
```

One thing to note here is that I am using a custom date table ranging from 0-1000. These are essentially days from joining for a customer (generated in the SQL query already), but this makes no difference for the code compared to using a standard date table (at least not in my other calculations). I am working with two tables, one is for the aforementioned custom time dimension (only includes [VintageDay] and [VintageMonth]), and another is the fact table that records all the transactions for all customers. The IF condition is something that I use with cumulative sums and at least in that context it removes the annoying behaviour where the latest calculated value is repeated to the end of my time dimension table.

In the fact table, I have the following columns: [Date], [UserId], [EventTypeId], [VintageDay]

What I would need is to be able to find and repeat the last effective event (there are many as identified by [EventTypeId] in the CALCULATE and then repeat it until the latest of any event for that customer, also over those periods where there are no events (this is not absolutely mandatory, but preferable). If I use SUM in the second CALCULATE, then the formula simply adds the new granted limit to the previous one and works like a cumulative sum. Additionally, I would have to be able to aggregate this over all customers, which are identified by their respective [UserId]'s.

All help is much appreciated, as I have been working on this for hours and hours and can't figure out a solution.

Comment: Are you effectively trying to find the limit for each customer at a specified 'vintage'?

Comment: If it helps, the problem is identical with a conventional time dimension. In this case the code would be expressed as follows:
`=IF (
MIN ( Dim_Time[Date] )
    <= CALCULATE ( MAX ( Fact_AccountEvent[Date] ) );
CALCULATE (
    MAX ( Fact_AccountEvent[Amount] );
    Fact_AccountEvent[EventTypeId] = 705;
    FILTER (
        ALL ( Dim_Time[Date] );
        Dim_Time[Date] <= MAX ( Dim_Time[Date] )
    )
))`

Customer who would have a 705 event at [Date] = 31.1.2014 of [Amount] = 500, and another at [Date] = 15.2.2014 of [Amount] = 1000 then I'd like to show 500 for the period 31.1.2014-15.2.2014

Comment: If another customer would have a limit of 800 also for the same time period, then I would like to get 1300 as a total limit (sum of row for dates in that range), but my piece of code would return 800.

Comment: can you please post some sample data?

Comment: Here is a sample dataset with two customers:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1IQmH8eS4kyVVc4ekNXQ2M2b0E/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hey, it seems that you use the calculation, that can be called "inventory valuation" and is described here http://www.daxpatterns.com/cumulative-total/ in great detail. But the calculation just works if the amount tracks the change, meaning on the 15.2.2014 there would be +500. I would suggest that you change the content of your "factcolumn" to movement, but nevertheless I will have a closer look to your question during the weekend. Hope this helps Tom

Comment: Yeah the inventory calculation doesn't really work. If it helps, UserId could be considered as ProductId and the credit limit as the latest price. Then the Fact_AccountEvent would record the latest price for a set of products. How to retrieve the latest price for any product and sum those up?